# How can I create new list from existing list?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list

```
List<Student>

class Student{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string School { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use above list and create or fill that data into

```
List<Person>

class Person{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Help me..

Thanx

Comment: does class `Person` and `Student` have some kind of relation?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That should do the trick

```
List<Person> persons = students.Select(student => new Person {FirstName = student.FirstName, LastName = student.LastName}).ToList();
```

Comment: +1 linq is the way to go here... if you avoid the fact that it looks like `Student` should inherit `Person`.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe the easiest solution is to inherit Student from Person (a student IS a person).

This way you don't have to copy/convert the list at all.

The result would be something like (done without IDE):

List

```
public class Person{ 
    public string FirstName { get; set; } 
    public string LastName { get; set; } 
} 

class Student : Person{ 
    public string School { get; set; } 
} 

List<Student> ... 

List<Person> ...
```

Answer (score 4):

If there is no explicit inheritance between `Student` and `Person` you can use a projection:

```
List<Student> ls = ...;

List<Person> lp = 
   ls.Select( 
     student => 
        new Person() 
        { 
            FirstName = student.FirstName, 
            LastName = student.LastName 
        } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have

```
List<Student> k= new List<Student>();
//add some students here
List<Person> p= k.select(s=>new Person() { FirstName = student.FirstName, LastName = student.LastName });
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep the person class as is.

```
class Person {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Make the `Student` class derive from `Person` and add the School property.

```
class Student : Person {
    public string School { get; set; }
}
```

You can now add a `Student` to a List of `Person`s.

```
var persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add(new Student());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fill data into another list by following way:

```
 listPerson = (from student in listStudent
                          select new Person
                          {
                              FirstName = student.FirstName,
                              LastName = student.LastName
                          }).ToList<Person>();
```